# display multiple term post from taxonomy in a single page

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms

I have custom post type name "resources" and taxonomy called "type" with lot of terms in it. I do not want to create custom template for each term like taxonomy-type-{term}.php every time I add new term.

What I am trying to achieve here is a single page where it handle to check each terms. If the current term is "24622", show content and so on, but I want it dynamic so I don't want to input term ID each time a new term created.

The code that I use that works so far for single term is this:

```
<?php
$args = array (
'post_type' => 'resources',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'type',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => 24622 //I WANT IT DYNAMIC
     )
  )
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
     while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        //Output what you want
   echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
      endwhile;
}
?>
```

Please help. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is the code that works for now but it fetches posts wrong order.

```
// get all terms used by current post for specific category
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID() , 'type');
// if $terms is array convert array of term objects to array of term IDs
if(is_array($terms)){
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms, 'term_id');
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $post_ids[] = $term->term_id;
}
// proceed with tax query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $term->term_id
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
    while ($loop->have_posts()):
        $loop->the_post();

        // Output what you want

        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

[image]

If I click the "Case studies (2)" it supposed to show 2 posts but show 1 post. In "Advocacy maps (1)", it shows 2 posts.

Post 1 is related to "Case studies" and "Advocacy maps" terms
Post 2 is related to "Case studies" and "Land monitoring reports"

Comment: "Check each terms" against what, there must be more to your single page than the above code?
Where will the dynamic term come from?

Comment: If im viewing "management" term, the code should compare if the current page is management term. This will show all post under management term. The above code only check 1 term (24622) but I want it dynamically check the term first and show post under that term. No more content above that code.

Comment: Where you have change the tax query term to 'terms' => $term->term_id, this will now only search the term id, being the last term the foreach loop found. If you change it to the  $post_ids, it will search an array of ID's found, the same as the wp_list_pluck.
Something is further wrong here and needs looking into further.. maybe the rest of your code.

Comment: The three links image you posted, where is this displayed, on which page?

Comment: It display in custom taxonomy page taxonomy-type.php

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your time answering my unclear question. The code I found is the one that Im looking for. Thank you again :)

```
<?php 
//http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters
$term_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
        if ( !$term_slug )
        return;
        else
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
                     array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'gallery_category',
                       'field' => 'slug',
                       'terms' => $term_slug,
                       'posts_per_page' => 10
                     )
                   )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try the following code:

```
// get all terms used by current post for specific category
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID() , 'type');
// if $terms is array convert array of term objects to array of term IDs
if(is_array($terms)){
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms, 'term_id');
// proceed with tax query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $term_ids
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
    while ($loop->have_posts()):
        $loop->the_post();

        // Output what you want

        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

This will return all posts having the same term OR terms as current post.
Can try and let me know if OK

Comment: Hi malisa, thanks for you time. However, the code didnt work. It show blank. I also tried changing the code and still no success.

Comment: What did you change.. I just saw there is a error on my behalf in the first part.. $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID() , 'category'); Should be $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID() , 'type');

Comment: put this in your footer and see if anything is output. $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID() , 'type');
print_r($terms);

Comment: Somehow it works by adding the 
<code>foreach($terms as $term) {
    $post_ids[] = $term->term_id;
}

and change the 'terms' => $term_ids to 'terms' => $term->term_id

Comment: It works as is perfectly well on my set up, but anyway, I'm glad you got it to work, maybe answer your own question with the code you ended up using to make it work.. help maybe others

Comment: The problem is. It fetches post wrong. Like if I got 4 kind of term say "term One" to "term Four", then I have 2 posts. 1st post has 2 terms like "term One" and "term Three" then the 2nd post has "term One" and "term two". If I check the "term One" supposed it will display my 2 posts but it only show 1 post, but the term Two, that supposed to show only 1 post, it shows 2 posts.

Comment: Here is the terms that I am talking about.
https://s22.postimg.org/faigoa741/ilc_error.jpg

If I click the "Case studies" it supposed to show 2 posts but it only show 1 post. but if I click "advocacy map" which it has 1 post, it shows 2 posts.